Is there any way to show the buttons in a div during mouseover a div, and hide the buttons in a div during mouseout a div?
I'd like to ask is there a way to "hide" a div while showing the button inside a div when the mouse is over the div, while "showing" the div again without the buttons when the mouse is not over the div?
Update: I'd clarify again more precisely what effect I want to achieve. When I move my mouse over the div, I want the text "a" to be hidden, showing up all the buttons and the text of the button inside the div, while turning the background color into light blue, and the text color into black. When I move away my mouse from the div, I want all the buttons and the text of the buttons in the div to be hidden, showing up again the text "a" only, while turning the bg color into black, and the text color into white.


const a = document.getElementById("a");
let btns = document.getElementsByTagName("#firstItem > .a > button");
let btnsA = Array.from(btns);

a.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {

  btnsA.forEach((element) => {
    element.style["display"] = "flex";
  });
  
  a.style["color"] = "#56F1FF";
});

a.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {

  btnsA.forEach((element) => {
    element.style["display"] = "none";
  });
  
  a.style["color"] = "#FFFFFF";
});
* {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

#firstItem {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#frame {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
}

section #firstItem div {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

section #firstItem div:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #56F1FF;
}

section #firstItem #a {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

section #firstItem #a button {
  display: none;
  background-color: #56F1FF;
  color: #000000;
}
<section>
  <div id="firstItem">
    <div id="a">a
      <button>a1</button>
      <button>a2</button>
      <button>a3</button>
      <button>a4</button>
      <button>a5</button>
      <button>a6</button>
    </div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="b">c</div>
    <div class="b">d</div>
    <div class="b">e</div>
    <div class="b">f</div>
    <div class="b">g</div>
    <div class="b">h</div>
  </div>
  <div id="frame">
  </div>
</section>




So if I move over the C, the back background and all other letters are hidden?

You already put "hide" in quotes, probably because you realized that if it was actually hidden, the buttons inside of course would get hidden together with it. So what is your actual definition of "hide" here, how is this supposed to behave, exactly?

I'd like the buttons and the letters on the buttons to show up, with their background color turning into light blue and the text color turning into black, the text "a" on the div should be "hidden", when the mouse is over the div "a". When I move out my mouse, I want it to show the text "a" on the div again, but not all the buttons and the text of the buttons, with the bg color turning to black and the text color turning into white.

Can't you do most of it through CSS instead directly? You might need to put the "a" text inside a span or so to interact with it, but I don't necessarily see why you would do this logic in javascript

You could create two div inside your div "a" , one for the text  and one for the buttons and set the visibility of the sub-div on the main div mouse over.


const a = document.getElementById("a");
const aText = document.getElementById("a-text");
const aButtons = document.getElementById("a-buttons");

a.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  a.style["color"] = "#56F1FF";
  aText.style["display"] = "none";
  aButtons.style["display"] = "flex";
});

a.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  aText.style["display"] = "flex";
  aButtons.style["display"] = "none";

  a.style["color"] = "#FFFFFF";
});
* {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

#firstItem {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#frame {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
}

section #firstItem div {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

section #firstItem div:hover {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #56F1FF;
}

section #firstItem #a {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

section #firstItem #a button {
  display: none;
  background-color: #56F1FF;
  color: #000000;
}
<section>
  <div id="firstItem">
    <div id="a">
      <div id="a-text">a</div>
      <div id="a-buttons">
        <button>a1</button>
        <button>a2</button>
        <button>a3</button>
        <button>a4</button>
        <button>a5</button>
        <button>a6</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="b">c</div>
    <div class="b">d</div>
    <div class="b">e</div>
    <div class="b">f</div>
    <div class="b">g</div>
    <div class="b">h</div>
  </div>
</section>



the buttons show on mouse over and text show otherwise

If your use case is to make the box white (invisible) during hover you can do it as:


const a = document.getElementById("a");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("#firstItem > .hoverable > button");

let btnsA = Array.from(btns);

a.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  btnsA.forEach((element) => {
element.style["display"] = "flex";
  });
});

a.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  btnsA.forEach((element) => {
element.style["display"] = "none";
  });
});
* {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: flex;
}

#firstItem {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

#frame {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
}

section #firstItem div {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

section #firstItem div:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  
}
<section>
  <div id="firstItem">
<div id="a" class="hoverable">a</div>
<div id="b" class="hoverable">b</div>
<div id="c" class="hoverable">c</div>
<div id="d" class="hoverable">d</div>
<div id="e" class="hoverable">e</div>
<div id="f" class="hoverable">f</div>
<div id="g" class="hoverable">g</div>
<div id="h" class="hoverable">h</div>
  </div>
  <div id="frame"></div>
</section>



